# Magento cannot get session value on another page

Tags: php, session, magento

On List page I am setting the session value, and can access there. But on Product view page I cannot get value.

```
  <?php 
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCategoryProductsIds($_catProductIds);

  $all_product_ids = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCategoryProductsIds();
  print_r($all_product_ids); 
  ?>
```

Thanks for any suggestions, I have been stuck !!!!

One interesting thing to note: this is working as expected in Safari, but Chrome and IE are producing the problem above.

Comment: might be helpful: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/11729/#t58439

Answer (score 0):

Set a Session value into a session Id in magento is little bit different. If you want to follow the Magento process than you must have to write the code given below to set a value and get a value of a particular Session Id.

To set Session write:

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('session_Id'); ?>
```

To get that session value write:

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('session_Id'); ?>
```